# login com varios acesso no angular

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb

o meu problema é o seguinte estou a tentar por o meu login com varios niveis de acesso como se for nivel 1 entra como superadministrador se for 2 entra como administrador e se for 3 entra como empregado 
estou a usar o angular 7 nodejs e mongodb
segue-se o codigo
auth.service.ts

```
`getUserDetails(username,password){ return this.http.post('api/login',{ username, password }`) }
```

login component

```
login() {
      let username = this.loginForm.value.username;
         let password = this.loginForm.value.password;
      this.Auth.getUserDetails(username,password).subscribe(data =>{
        if(data.success){
      this.router.navigate(['homepage'])
      this.Auth.setLoggedIn(true)
      //sdsadad
        }else{
        document.getElementById("erro").style.visibility = "visible";
        window.setTimeout("location.href='login'",3000);

        }
      })

      }
```

nodejs

```
 app.post('/api/login', async (req,res)=>{
      const {username,password}=req.body
      const resp = await User.findOne({ username: username}).select('+password')
      if(password==null){
        res.json({success:false,
          message:"  password can not be empty"
        })
      }else if(username==null){
        res.json({success:false,
          message:" username can not be empty "
        })
      }
      else if(!resp){
        res.json({success:false,
          message:"incorrect password"
        })

      }
      else if(!await bcrypt.compare(password, resp.password)){
    //if(!resp){

      res.json({success:false,
        message:"incorrect password"
      })
    }else {
      ///sessions
      req.session.user=username
      req.session.save()

      res.json({
        success:true
      })

    }
    })
```

o que tenho que alterar
o codigo completo esta neste link
https://github.com/Kammikazy/project

Comment: qual o problema ou erro?

Comment: o problema é que não sei o que tenho alterar no meu codigo

Comment: Nesse caso sua pergunta está muito genérica pro stackOverflow, tem mil formas de ter esse comportamento. Uma delas seria retornar um objeto usuário e ali vc fazer as lógicas de acesso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

esta foi a minha solução para resolver o meu problema

```
    login() {
      let username = this.loginForm.value.username;
         let password = this.loginForm.value.password;
      this.Auth.getUserDetails(username,password).subscribe(data =>{
        if(data.success){

      if(data.nivel=='1'){
      this.router.navigate(['homepage'])
      this.Auth.setLoggedIn(true)


      }
    else if(data.nivel=='2'){
      this.router.navigate(['homepage'])
     this.Auth.setLoggedIn(true)
      }
      else if(data.nivel=='3'){
        this.router.navigate(['homepage'])
      this.Auth.setLoggedIn(true)


        }
      //sdsadad
        }else{
        document.getElementById("erro").style.visibility = "visible";
        window.setTimeout("location.href='login'",3000);

        }
      })

      }
node index
app.post('/api/login', async (req,res)=>{
  const {username,password}=req.body
  const resp = await User.findOne({ username: username}).select('+password')
  if(password==null){
    res.json({success:false,
      message:"  password can not be empty"
    })

  }else if(username==null){

    res.json({success:false,
      message:" username can not be empty "
    })
  }
  else if(!resp){
    res.json({success:false,
      message:"incorrect password"
    })

  }
  else if(!await bcrypt.compare(password, resp.password)){
//if(!resp){

  res.json({success:false,
    message:"incorrect password"
  })
}else {
  ///sessions
  const resp = await User.findOne({ username: username}, function(err, result) {
      const {username}=req.body
    if (err) throw err;
    var obj= result
  req.session.user=username
  req.session.nivel=obj.nivel
  req.session.save()


  res.json({
    success:true,
    nivel:obj.nivel
  })
});
}

})
```